# Tomcat 8.5.15 not loading static resources

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat8, css, eclipse

I have upgraded my local tomcat from version 8.0.36 to 8.5.15. I have a project that has static resources (css, js and vm) inside a project in an Eclipse workspace, linked in the pom profile properties of the main project with the tags 
    `<static.resources>`
and `<documents.resources>`.

When I execute the project, randomly during the navigation, at a certain point, a lot of css and js (not vm) are not loaded anymore and they response 400. When I have upgraded the tomcat. I only have copied users, datasources, and libs. Is there some configuration that I may have missed?

If I run the tomcat from eclipse or start it with a batch file, the result is the same.

**UPDATE 1**

I have found the bug, some resources inside the .vm are linked in this way

`<link href='${baseUrl}/${storefrontPath}/css/all.css${assetVersion}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link>`

where `${assetVersion}` is equal at `?_v=${project.version}` where project.version is the version inside the pom.

If i write the url of the static resource in the browser i can find it also without version number but i don't have to write the {

**UPDATE 2**

I solved my problem with this solutions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41150474/5222931

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44005213/5222931

both works